# How to know in spartacus application what preferences are updated on gigya screensets?

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront, gigya

Is there a way to override `onProfileUpdateEventHandler` method in `CdcJsService`? From code in `cdc-root.module.ts` it looks to me it would be very complicated to customize this service.

To be more specific, I want to have access to granted consents (`preferences` field) in `response` parameter of that method. I know this field is there, but it is not passed further to `this.userProfileFacade.updata(userDetails)`. So I do not have info about changed preferences when I subscribe to `UserAccountChangedEvent`. I only have `firstName` and `lastName` in this object.

Or is there any other way to hook into event when preferences are changed through gigya screensets?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: whenever a user submit the screen, in the network tab you can see there is accounts.getaccountInfo is called either you can extract preferences data from there or you can directly call this API to extract any information you like. For your reference I am attaching the SAP link of getAccountInfo call which you can use, https://help.sap.com/viewer/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/GIGYA/en-US/cab69a86edae49e2be93fd51b78fc35b.html

Comment: @sameer Thank you for your response. As I remember, I indeed ended up using getAccountInfo as you suggested.